# Mark a line in my RecyclerView on long touch (press)

Tags: java, android, xml

I need help with me RecyclerView. I've build a normal RecyclerView like this here `https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial` and now I need your help.

I want to mark a line (the marked line should be grey) in my RecylcerView on long touch (press) with a short vibration from the device to show a delete icon in the marked row. When the row is marked I want to show the deleting icon instead of the profile image. With clicking the back button from the device I'll remove this mark. How can I do this? Thanks for your help!

Row after long click (press/hold):

[image]

This is my adapter:

```js
package de.schoolapp.schoolapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Johannes on 20.02.2017.
 */

public class BenutzerlisteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BenutzerlisteAdapter.MyBenutzerlisteHolder> {
    private List<Benutzerliste> userList;
    private final Context customContext;

    public class MyBenutzerlisteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView userRowName, userRowPermission;

        public MyBenutzerlisteHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            userRowName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userRowName);
            userRowPermission = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userRowPermission);

        }
    }

    public BenutzerlisteAdapter(java.util.List<Benutzerliste> userList, Context customContext) {
        this.userList = userList;
        this.customContext = customContext;
    }

    @Override
    public MyBenutzerlisteHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.benutzerliste_liste_row, parent, false);

        return new MyBenutzerlisteHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyBenutzerlisteHolder holder, int position) {

        final Benutzerliste userFillList = userList.get(position);

        holder.userRowName.setText(customContext.getString(R.string.userRowName) + " " + userFillList.getVorname() + " " + userFillList.getName());
        holder.userRowPermission.setText(customContext.getString(R.string.userRowPermission) + " " + userFillList.getBerechtigung());

        // OnClickListener for holder
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your adapter code so others can modify according to your requirement,

Comment: @JerinAMathews Did it